# Como fazer a chamada do método Arrays.sort (array, new metodoOrd()) no Java?

Tags: java, array

Sabendo que a tenho uma classe com um array de objetos e outra classe que implementa a interface `Comparator`.

Gostaria de qualquer exemplo só pra eu aprender e poder ordenar um array de objetos pelo nome deles na minha classe que implementa `Comparator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para ordenar um *array* de objetos em Java, usa-se geralmente métodos prontos da classe `java.util.Arrays`.

Sendo `T` um certo tipo de objeto (classe), o método mais comum contém a seguinte assinatura:

```java
Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? extends T>)
```

Tipos primitivos e Strings não precisam de um `Comparator`, afinal já existem versões sobrecarregadas do `sort` para isso.

Mas, por exemplo, se você tem uma classe `Cliente`, você deve então passar um array de clientes (`Cliente[]`) e uma implementação de `Comparator` do tipo `T` ou alguma subclasse de `T`, que é o significado de `? extends T`.

A implementação do `Comparator` pode ser feita como uma classe anônima ou num arquivo `.java` normalmente.

## Exemplo

### `Cliente.java`

```java
public class Cliente {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Cliente(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

}
```

### Criando um array

A partir da classe acima, podemos criar um array qualquer:

```java
Cliente[] clientes = {
        new Cliente("Bruno", 30),
        new Cliente("Maria", 28),
        new Cliente("Carlos", 40)
};
```

### Ordenando por `nome`

Veja agora um exemplo de ordenação por `nome`:

```java
Arrays.sort(clientes, new Comparator<Cliente>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Cliente b1, Cliente b2) {
        //TODO testar nulos
        return b1.getNome().compareTo(b2.getNome()); //delegar para comparador da String
    }
});
```

O que foi feito acima é simplesmente implementar o método `compare` da interface `Comparator` e delegar a execução ao método `compareTo` do atributo `nome`, que é `String`.

#### Versão com *lambda expression* (Java 8)

No Java 8, com uso de *lambdas*, a coisa fica ainda mais fácil:

```java
Arrays.sort(clientes, (Cliente b1, Cliente b2) 
    -> b1.getNome().compareTo(b2.getNome()));
```

### Ordenando por `idade`

Se quiséssemos, por exemplo, ordenar por `idade`, poderíamos mudar a implementação da seguinte forma:

```java
Arrays.sort(clientes, new Comparator<Cliente>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Cliente b1, Cliente b2) {
        //TODO testar nulos
        if (b1.getIdade() > b1.getIdade()) return 1;
        if (b1.getIdade() < b2.getIdade()) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Note que o método `compare` refere-se a uma comparação individual entre dois clientes quaisquer do vetor. Este método é usado internamente pelo algoritmo do `sort`.

O retorno `1` significa que o primeiro elemento é maior que o segundo. O retorno `-1` é o contrário. E o retorno `0` significa que eles são iguais para esse critério de comparação.

#### Versão com *lambda expression* (Java 8)

Vejamos também o segundo exemplo de ordenação também em Java 8:

```java
Arrays.sort(clientes, (Cliente b1, Cliente b2) -> {
    if (b1.getIdade() > b1.getIdade()) return 1;
    if (b1.getIdade() < b2.getIdade()) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

## Considerações

Note que o array é modificado pelo método `sort`, portanto se quiser manter o array original é preciso fazer uma cópia. Para fazer uma cópia de array de forma simples e eficiente, use o método estático `System.arraycopy()`.

O algoritmo usado no método `sort` é conhecido como *timsort*, descrito [neste link](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt).

O código funcional do exemplo está disponível no meu [GitHub](https://github.com/utluiz/java-playground/tree/master/random-code/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/comparator).

Comment: Sem palavras para agradecer a ajuda.